# Google Maps grid lines appearing over custom markers on Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, safari

This is only happening for me on Safari (v7.1.7). My custom markers have what appears to be white map gridlines appearing. I don't know if this is a problem with my code, a problem with Safari, or a problem with Google Maps.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/v2QHAOG.jpg]

**EDITED TO ADD**

Link to page affected: http://momentumdevelopments.ca/2015new-preview/projects/bpr-lofts/

I think this might be a js conflict somewhere on the page, as I can't get the same thing to happen on a JS Fiddle.

Comment: Hi afterthree, it would help us if you showed us relevant code that you tried, and what output you expected.

Comment: Most likely a css problem. Can't tell from a picture.

Comment: Link is here: http://momentumdevelopments.ca/2015new-preview/projects/bpr-lofts/

Comment: I tried to recreate in a fiddle, but I can't get the problem to appear. Which leads me to believe it may be some sort of js conflict somewhere? I also can't get it to happen on a different page that also has very similar Google Maps code on it... http://momentumdevelopments.ca/2015new-preview/map/

Comment: We have had a similar issue reported by a customer using safari where the custom map markers have horizontal lines in them (suspect this is the same grid lines, but our markers are smaller)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but adding "optimized: false" to marker config fixed this issue in safari for me:

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            optimized: false
        });

Also found this solution here: [Google Maps - Strange vertical and horizontal lines at certain zoom levels in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031678/google-maps-strange-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-at-certain-zoom-levels-in-sa)

Comment: It does fix it, BUT If you do that you will lose functionality including the information pop up boxes when you click the markers.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour may be a result of a custom browser-zoom, so check if the browser-zoom is set to default