# Google Maps - Strange vertical and horizontal lines at certain zoom levels in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having an issue with Google Maps where these weird lines are coming up over my map at certain zoom levels in Safari. If I resize my browser they go away for a second then come back. I think it's to do with the Google Map being inside a container which has "margin: 0 auto;" as I tested it in a full width Google Map and there were no issues.

[image]

EDIT:

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ojdavey/84ewc0jx/16/

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS:

```
var map;

function initialize() {


var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.255338, 144.34334),
zoom: 10,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
draggable: true,
zoomControl: true,
scrollwheel: false,
disableDefaultUI: true,
};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.272048, 144.479249);
  var icon1 =   'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/ISO_7010_E003_-_First_aid_sign.svg/2000px-ISO_7010_E003_-_First_aid_sign.svg.png';

var markerImage1 = {
  url: icon1,
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 12)
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map,
  icon: markerImage1
});
}
initialize();
```

CSS:

```
#map {
background-color: #000;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about the little white lines at the tile boundaries, they are probably css related.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm talking about. How are they CSS related though? Is there a fix?

Comment: Are you positive that the posted code reproduces the issue (I don't have Safari available), and the posted code is not a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've updated it with a JS Fiddle link

Comment: That looks OK in Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) on Windows7, but not in Chrome.  Looks like it is a problem with whatever is rendering the icon on canvas.  Setting `{optimized: false}` in the markerOptions fixes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it is a problem with whatever is rendering the icon on canvas.  Setting `{optimized: false}` in the markerOptions fixes it.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.255338, 144.34334),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    draggable: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.272048, 144.479249);

  var markerImage1 = {
    url: icon1,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 12)
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: markerImage1,
    optimized: false     // <-- this fixes the artifacts
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var icon1 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 350px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me on Safari on a Mac

Comment: It works for me in all browsers I have access to on Windows.  The version of Safari I am running is fairly old.